# How good a fit is question 17757 for this site?

Tags: discussion

How should [questions like this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17757/can-you-ask-for-a-miracle-to-happen-in-your-duas) be dealt with?  should they be closed, and if so as what? should they just be left to get down-voted? or should such questions get deleted?

The issue I see with the question are a couple.  One is that it is a one liner which shows lack of research effort (not that it is even needed in this case), and two most "can" questions have only two answers "Yes (sure)" or "No", which in the case of this specific question would lead to answers not of good/high quality, as well as the answers would seem more like comments.

Answer (score 1):

It should, at the very least, probably be downvoted for showing no research effort.  There is absolutely no indication that the questioner has put any effort at all into solving this problem themselves, not even to the point of explaining why he thinks it's even a question worth asking.

I've brought up this issue on Meta before (see "[What should we do about no-effort-shown questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/829/22)") and my opinion then is much the same as it is now: Questions of this sort need to be actively *discouraged* on the site, and downvoting is the ideal way to do this.  If posts of this quality are allowed not only to persist on the site, but to garner upvotes which suggest that they're *welcome*, the overall quality of the site will only degrade.

Whether they should be closed as well is a bit trickier; many of the questions of this nature can easily fall under "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion Based" because they give absolutely no focus or criteria for what actually makes any particular answer better than another, but that's really a judgment call (and often one that requires some degree of domain expertise).