# O Muslims of StackExchange Don’t You Fear Allah

Tags: discussion, quran, sunnah

BismillahiRahmaniRaheem.
I am Muslim, despite my very Jewish name. The Islam section of StackExchange is what prompted to make my account, not because I seek to ask a question or even answer one. But because of the misguidance I notice within it. From people asking my questions, to Muslims who lack knowledge of the Quran alone the Sunnah. To people answering those questions, that fall under the guidelines of a fatwa, yet they answer them as if they are qualified by way of their knowledge. When they are in fact not scholars or even students of knowledge. A person might ask what is the big deal answering questions without knowledge, is because Allah (azwajal) has permitted the answering of questions only for people with knowledge of the Quran and Sunnah who have studied. Meaning if the one answering has not mastered the branches of knowledge, then he is a sinner. Even if he answered the question posed correctly, although most do not answer correctly. And that person falls under the verse in the Quran in which Allah (azwajal) says in Surah Al Isra (translated to), “And do not pursue that of which you have no knowledge. Indeed, the hearing, the sight and the heart - about all those [one] will be questioned (ayat 36).” So one will be questioned by Allah (azwajal) in regards to all that which they have done, and said. So the one who answers, must know and to know is to have ilm (knowledge) of tawheed, the Quran, Sunnah, and the way of the Salaf (righteous students of the companions of the Prophet [peace and blessings be upon him]) And likewise the one who asks must know who to ask, how can one expect the one who is like himself a Muslim who has not studied, to know the answer to a question that is important and pertains to the sanctity of his life. Allah (azwajal) says in Surah Nahl (translated to), “And We sent not before you except men to whom We revealed [Our message]. So ask the people of the message if you do not know (ayat 43).” So the person who asks, while knowing the one he is asking is ignorant or a person of desires and misguided, then he is also sinful in that asking. Because Allah (azwajal) commands that the people of knowledge, those who understand his religion, are gone to for justice and advice. So to seek out the oppose is a sin. And this matter should not be taken lightly, both paths lead a person to Shirk and innovation. Which leads to Jahannam. This is why Allah (azwajal) says in Surah l-An Am (translated to), “Indeed, those who have divided their religion and become sects - you, [O Muhammad], are not [associated] with them in anything. Their affair is only [left] to Allah ; then He will inform them about what they used to do (ayat 159).” This is referring to those people who create parties amongst the Muslims by way of political or worldly gain, or by way of innovations (new matters that the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) never endorsed nor came with, and nor did his companions engage in) in the Sunnah. Answering fatwas with knowledge, and asking fatwas to people who may be misguided falls into this verse. Would you like that not only did Allah (azwajal) command the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon) him to free himself from you, but Allah (azwajal) frees himself from you because of your misguidance and changing his religion. This is danger of these matters on StackExchange. This is why we have Sufis, or people like the Taliban. Both of these groups commit haram by innovating into the religion. Many Sufi sects permit Music, when the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said, “The angels do not enter a home in which is a jingle or a bell, and the angels do not accompany a gathering in which is a bell.” Meaning every type of instrument, so whoever engages in listening to it, endorsing it, or even creating the instrument itself, is removed from the mercy of Allah (azwajal) until he repents. And yet Sufis permit it, knowing that it is haram, because they are people of desires, who seek to drive people away from the which will guide them and rectify their hearts. This is the danger of having no knowledge, like the Sufis, and calling to misguidance. So they occur their own sins, and the sins of those who follow them. But this is also the danger of not having knowledge yourself, so you know who to ask. But if you know they are misguided and you still ask, then no doubt you are like them and are sinful. And as for the Taliban, they abuse women. When Aisha (May Allah Be Pleased With Her) reported that, “The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, did not strike a servant or a woman, and he never struck anything with his hand.” They also bar women from gaining ilm, and I am not referring to secular knowledge, that is forbidden for both women and men. Why?, because it has free mixing and exposes Muslims to ill ideologies and religions. But the Taliban bar their women from even gaining Islamic knowledge. In Islam, knowledge comes before action. Without knowledge of the religion, how can one act upon that which is commanded upon them by Allah (azwajal). This is why the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon) him said, “Seeking knowledge is obligatory upon every Muslim.” This means every man or woman, young or old, rich or poor, and so on. The only ones exempt from this Hadith are those who live in a far far land, in seclusion away from the Muslims upon Tawheed and the Sunnah and they have no way of reaching the Muslims upon the correct path, the insane (people with mental disabilities), a very old and unaware man, the deaf man who has no way of hearing the truth or reading it, and those people who died before Allah (azwajal) sent a messenger to them in their time. Otherwise this Hadith includes essentially everyone including woman. This is why it is reported that, “A woman came to the Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, and she said, “O Messenger of Allah, only the men benefit from your speeches. Set a day for us when we can come to you and you will teach us what Allah has taught you.” The Prophet said, “Gather on an upcoming day at this place.” They gathered and the Prophet came and taught them what Allah had taught him. The Prophet said, “No woman among you will lose three children but that they will shield her from the Hellfire.” A woman said, “O Messenger of Allah, what if she only lost two children?” She repeated her question. The Prophet said three times, “Even two.” And yet the Taliban bar their women from this. They also encourage the killing of innocent lives, especially Muslim lives. This is no doubt the way of the Khawarijj (a sect in Islam - who revolt against the Ruler which is haram - and who make takfeer upon the Ummah (declaring a Muslim to be a disbeliever). This is despite the fact that Allah (azwajal) says in Surah Al Maidah (translated to), “Because of that, We decreed upon the Children of Israel that whoever kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the land - it is as if he had slain mankind entirely. And whoever saves one - it is as if he had saved mankind entirely. And Our messengers had certainly come to them with clear proofs. Then indeed many of them, [even] after that, throughout the land, were transgressors (ayat 32).” Meaning to kill a soul is from the greatest of crimes after shirk. This is why the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said, “The first of matters to be judged between people will be cases of murder.” This is in regards to the day of judgement. And in another narration he (peace and blessings be upon him) said, “Shedding sacred blood without just cause.” Yet and still the Taliban not only encourage this but engage in it themselves. Let alone the many other misguided groups that have arisen in the history of Islam, such as the Deobandis, Barelvis, Shia, Ashari, Maturidi, Ismailis etc. This shows one the importance striving to gain knowledge, and to know who is rightly guided and to not speak until Allah (azwajal) has permitted you to do so by way of the amount and quality of knowledge you have. So one must pay heed to these matters. I hope the Muslims reading this understand my goal. As all of these misguided groups, and this includes those on Stack Exchange answering fatwas whilst they are not qualified to do so, lead one to the path of the Fire. Because it is not the path which Allah (azwajal) has ordained for the Muslims nor is it the way of our Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him). This is why the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said, “Whomever Allah guides, no one can lead him astray. Whomever Allah sends astray, no one can guide him. The truest word is the Book of Allah, and the best guidance is the guidance of Muhammad. The evilest matters in religion are those that are newly invented, for every newly invented matter is an innovation, every innovation is misguidance, and every misguidance is in the Hellfire.” And he (peace and blessings be upon him) also said, “What befell the children of Isra'il will befall my Ummah, step by step, such that if there was one who had intercourse with his mother in the open, then there would be someone from my Ummah who would do that. Indeed the children of Isra'il split into seventy-two sects, and my Ummah will split into seventy-three sects. All of them are in the Fire Except one sect." He said: "And which is it O Messenger of Allah?" He said: "What I am upon and my Companions." It is not correct what people say that these hadiths are not referring to the state of the Muslims now, or that the one sect (Ahlus Sunnah Wal Jammah) does not exist, as these hadiths are not only authentic. But to deny them means to have denied the Sunnah of the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) and to deny his Sunnah is disbelief. As Allah (azwajal) says in Surah Najm (translated to), “Nor does he speak from [his own] inclination (ayat 3).” Meaning the Sunnah of the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) is revelation from Allah (azwajal). And to disbelieve in Allah (azwajal)’ revelation is Kufr. So my goal with this account is mentioned and hopefully I maintain. And I am human and will error, if you have knowledge, correct me.

Comment: Please consider formatting, this is practically unreadable as it is. Either way, it belongs on [meta], not the main site, so I am migrating it.

Comment: Some related posts that were already answered: https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/what-is-the-purpose-of-islam-se-and-its-authenticity-to-answering-questions-abo 
https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/question-quality 
https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1709/what-is-authenticity-of-this-forum 
https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3123/authentic-answers-of-questions 
https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/who-can-answer-questions